# Jquery make dropdown menu selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down menu, when I select any option, the page redirects. Now I want to make the page as the selected item in the drop down. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<select class="MobileDropDown">
    <option value="/">Home</option>
    <option value="/technology">Topics</option>
    <option value="/about">About Us</option>
    <option value="/vendor">Vendor Directory</option>
    <option value="/popular-research">Popular White Papers</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".MobileDropDown").change(function(){
        window.location.href = $(this).val();
    });

    var URLMobile = window.location.href.split('/');

    $(".MobileDropDown option").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == '/' + URLMobile[3]) {
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
    });
</script>
```

I am sure this is not the best way to do this, but how would I fix this?

Comment: What do you want, again?

Comment: You only need to apply a value to the select. The option should then be selected by default. E.g.: [`$('.MobileDropDown').val('/about');`](http://jsbin.com/aluHeGOT/1/).

Comment: `var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");` Gets the address of whatever was clicked.

Comment: Just do: `$(".MobileDropDown").val("/" + URLMobile[3]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".MobileDropDown").change(function(){
        window.location.href = $(this).val();
    });

    var URLMobile = window.location.href.split('/');

    $(".MobileDropDown").val("/" + URLMobile[3]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the selecting process like this,

```
$(".MobileDropDown option:contains(" + '/' + URLMobile[3] + ")").prop('selected',true);
```

or

```
$(".MobileDropDown").val("/" + URLMobile[3]);
```